# Retrieve a balanced color palette from an image in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to retrieve a balanced palette of colors (the top five colors) from an image; I've found some solutions that fetch the most popular colors in an image based on pixel colors, but this isn't always a balanced representation of the image, because photographs tend to have lots of different shades of a similar color.

For example, if I retrieve the most popular colors of this image:

[image].

Before you see the result you would expect yellow would be near the top, but because the sky is a fairly consistent color, the number of variations of the sky blue color is higher than anywhere else in the image (yellow doesn't even show up in the results until the 30th most popular color!).

Is it possible to retrieve a more balanced set of colors? What method should I use?

Here is the code that is demonstrating my problem:

```
@using System.Drawing;
@using System.Drawing.Imaging;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;

var img = "/myimage.jpg";
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(img))
{
    var colorsWithCount =
        GetPixels(bitmap)
            .GroupBy(color => color)
            .Select(grp =>
                new
                {
                    Color = grp.Key,
                    Count = grp.Count()
                })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
            .Take(5);

            foreach (var colorWithCount in colorsWithCount)
            {
                string hex = colorWithCount.Color.R.ToString("X2") + colorWithCount.Color.G.ToString("X2") + colorWithCount.Color.B.ToString("X2");

                <p>@hex: @colorWithCount.Count</p>
            }
}

public static IEnumerable<Color> GetPixels(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        {
            Color pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
            yield return pixel;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that yellow doesn't appear before the 30th position because there is several yellow colors in this image where blue color is more homogeneous.

First of all, it's complicated to make image processing on color image because there is a lot of parameters to define a color.
May be the first step would be to transform the image in gray scales so that it can be easier to work on levels of gray instead of colors.
After this, you can make a hysteresis thresholding on image gray levels: you can have 16 ranges of gray in the image by dividing the image spectrum by 16. 
After that, you can count the 5 more numerous levels of grays. 
By position you will be able to know the corresponding pixels on the color image and know the 5 more predominant colors.

You probably will get a range of yellow, not a simple color.